# Sprockets + Less @import issues?

Tags: css, ruby, less, assets, sprockets

It's not finding my @import'ed files.
If I use //=require on them it won't keep track of the variables I'm defining in other files so @import is the only option.

I've even tried using the full physical path like @import "/Users//Sites/project/stylesheets/test.less"; and it still cannot find the file.

They are in the same directory...

It seems there's a weird issue with Sprockets + LESS.

I'm not using RAILS, just a basic rack server with sprockets...

`Less::ParseError: 'activity.less' wasn't found. (in /Users/rountrjf/Sites/ce-platform/app/assets/stylesheets/app.less)`

Anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: check the hot fix , I am figuring out if there we can use some config till then use relative path name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix I found was give the relative path of the file in import

eg:

```
@import "app/assets/stylesheets/app.less";
```

It worked for me.

**Update**: proper soultion which I found was :

use this [sprockets-less](https://github.com/lloeki/sprockets-less) gem

works like a charm no relative path required

check my example [here](https://gist.github.com/3693101)

Comment: I'll give this a shot. However, I do believe I tried all different types of paths.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  Can't believe I didn't try that already... it's amazing the things you miss after a long day of staring at this sh*T

Answer (score 0):

Are you naming your files .css.less or just .less? Try adding .css.less which is what I have found I needed to do with Rails Assets Pipeline (sprockets). Since you are not using rails, this solution might work for you too since you are using sprockets.

Comment: This wasn't the issue, less & sprockets definitely do not require the use of ".css.less"
Thanks, though!